# What property is linking these two lists in vue.draggable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuedraggable, vue.draggable

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>Draggable 1</h3>
      <draggable class="list-group" :list="list1" group="people" @change="log">
        <div
          class="list-group-item"
          v-for="(element, index) in list1"
          :key="element.name"
        >
          {{ element.name }} {{ index }}
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <h3>Draggable 2</h3>
      <draggable class="list-group" :list="list2" group="people" @change="log">
        <div
          class="list-group-item"
          v-for="(element, index) in list2"
          :key="element.name"
        >
          {{ element.name }} {{ index }}
        </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>

    <rawDisplayer class="col-3" :value="list1" title="List 1" />

    <rawDisplayer class="col-3" :value="list2" title="List 2" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import draggable from "@/vuedraggable";
export default {
  name: "two-lists",
  display: "Two Lists",
  order: 1,
  components: {
    draggable
  },
  data() {
    return {
      list1: [
        { name: "John", id: 1 },
        { name: "Joao", id: 2 },
        { name: "Jean", id: 3 },
        { name: "Gerard", id: 4 }
      ],
      list2: [
        { name: "Juan", id: 5 },
        { name: "Edgard", id: 6 },
        { name: "Johnson", id: 7 }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.list.push({ name: "Juan" });
    },
    replace: function() {
      this.list = [{ name: "Edgard" }];
    },
    clone: function(el) {
      return {
        name: el.name + " cloned"
      };
    },
    log: function(evt) {
      window.console.log(evt);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is straight from the draggable documentation found here on the "View Code" button:
https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/two-lists

I am trying to understand what property is necessary to make it so each list knows the other is a drag and drop area. Unfortunately this isn't clarified in the doc, so anyone who can break it down I'd be ever so grateful!

I think it has something to do with

```
      <draggable class="list-group" :list="list1" group="people" @change="log">
```

but unsure

Comment: From what i can see, my guess is that the group property is the one connecting the lists. I haven't tried it myself but from looking at the git repo and the examples, everytime there are two lists they share the same group name.

Answer (score 2):

The `vue-draggable` library is, as stated on the repo's [README](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable), based on another library called [Sortable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable).
So anything related to the draggable options are from this library and you should refer to its documentation.

Here is the documentation for the [`group`](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#group-option) property:

> To drag elements from one list into another, both lists must have the same group value. You can also define whether lists can give away, give and keep a copy (clone), and receive elements.

So yes, this property is the one responsible to link two draggable lists.